# retrieve blob picture from mysql database c#

Tags: c#, mysql, blob

I use this code to retrieve my picture and it work corectly with a simple table that contain only blob but when i'm trying to adapt it for my table user that containt (cin,nom,prenom....,image)  exception that indicate

> "Paramétre non valid" (**not a valid parameter**)

```
        int bufferSize = 1000; 
        try
        {
            string SQL = "Select image from user ";

            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(SQL, db.Connection);
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "image");
            int c = ds.Tables["image"].Rows.Count;
            db.CloseConnection();

            if (c > 0)
            {
                Byte[] byteBLOBData = new Byte[bufferSize];
                byteBLOBData = (Byte[])(ds.Tables["image"].Rows[c - 1]["image"]);
                MemoryStream stmBLOBData = new MemoryStream(byteBLOBData);

                pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(stmBLOBData);
                MessageBox.Show("bien chargée");
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Connection Error!\n" + ex.Message, "Error Message",
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
```

Comment: In which line is the exception arisen?

Comment: I think that you don't have to fill a dataset but using directly a SqlDataReader

Comment: if  i delete the catch i dont get error and no result...

Answer (score 1):

Try this one...

```
DataTable userTable;
DataTable ds;

int cin;
string nom;
string prenom;
Byte[] ImageByte;

userTable = ds;
if (userTable == null)
    return false;
else
{
    if (userTable.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (DataRow userRow in userTable.Rows)
        {
            cin = Convert.ToInt32(userRow["cin"]);
            nom = userRow["nom"].ToString();
            prenom = userRow["prenom"].ToString();
            ImageByte = (Byte[])(userRow["image"]);
        }
    }
}
if (ImageByte != null)
{
    // You need to convert it in bitmap to display the imgage
    pictureBox1.Image = ByteToImage(ImageByte);
    pictureBox1.Refresh();
}

public static Bitmap ByteToImage(byte[] blob)
{
    MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream();
    byte[] pData = blob;
    mStream.Write(pData, 0, Convert.ToInt32(pData.Length));
    Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(mStream, false);
    mStream.Dispose();
    return bm;

}
```

Comment: thanks but i need just to get a blob picture into  picturebox

Comment: please check my updated answer.

you need to convert your byte array into bitmap. please check **ByteToImage(byte[] byteArray)** method

Answer (score 1):

```
byteBLOBData = ((Byte[])ds.Tables["image"].Rows[c - 1]["image"]);
```

This should solve it.

Comment: Can you add some explanation around your code, rather than just posting the answer?  Try to help people understand exactly which part was wrong, why it was wrong, and why your solution is what they need to apply.