# How to convert Blob value to Image

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I have a BLOB value in a MySQL database.

I've read several tutorials, but I can not find a solution.

Any idea how I can read the image (blob value) and view it in an ASP.NET Image component?

All info i found is about array convert to image, but I have a Blob value

Comment: In what kind of image component? Are you asking how to read bytes from the database? How to serve bytes as an image? What don't you understand?

Comment: have you tried `Image.FromStream` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35698114/retrieve-blob-picture-from-mysql-database-c-sharp

Comment: This is a asp.net project, Image.FromStream not exist.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [asp.net display image from byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39338359/asp-net-display-image-from-byte-array)

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to read the image from db and put in a MemoryStream, then show it in an image component? Something like :

```
            Byte[] byteBLOBData = new Byte[bufferSize];
            byteBLOBData = "read image from database"
            MemoryStream stmBLOBData = new MemoryStream(byteBLOBData);

            pictureBox.Image = Image.FromStream(stmBLOBData);
```

Reference : https://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/965811-retrieve-blob-picture-mysql-database-c

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.

The exact problem was the query...

Code finished...

```
Image picture = new Image();
            string queryImage = "SELECT image FROM news WHERE id = @id";
            using (MySqlConnection con1 = new MySqlConnection(servidor))
            {
                MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand(queryImage, con1);
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", rd[0]);
                con1.Open();
                byte[] bytesImage = (byte[])cmd1.ExecuteScalar();
                picture.ImageUrl = "data:image;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(bytesImage);
            }
```